# Is there a Twitter App Builder?

Tags: web-applications, twitter

I have a small fun Twitter app idea and I was wondering if there are Twitter app builders such as the ones you can find for iPhone?

If there aren't any. Are there good resources of learning how to put a Twitter app together?

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of [Open Source](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Open+source) projects on twitters website.  (My project 'twipler' is on that list).

Comment: Thanks Ian. Your app seems to emulate Twitter. Do you know of any app builders for Twitter. There are a lot for iPhone, e.g. appcelerator.com, mobileroadie.com,etc, but nothing for non-programmers to tinker with Twitter. btw- I upvoted your answer- that should take care of the -1. :)

Comment: Cheers. I hope you get some success with what you're trying to achieve. email me if you want some help w/ ideas etc.